# What does a "framework" actually mean?

Tags: frameworks

Can anybody tell me in SIMPLE words, what does it mean when we say *"I want to build a framework for blah..blah"*

Comment: Did you read the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)?  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Thanks Danny for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

From [Software Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) on Wikipedia:

> In computer programming, a software framework is an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by user code, thus providing application specific software. **A software framework is a universal, reusable software platform used to develop applications, products and solutions.** Software frameworks include support programs, compilers, code libraries, an application programming interface (API) and tool sets that bring together all the different components to enable development of a project or solution.

Thank you

Comment: Make sure to include excerpts or summaries when providing links.